# Text resizes on animation transition

Tags: ios, animation, uiviewanimationtransition

When trying to animate a view using `[UIView transitionWithView]` the text resizes, while I don't appear to be doing anything with the font size.

The view contains three buttons. Two buttons representing 'tabs' and a single button to edit the text on those tabs. One of the tabs is disabled (to represent the active tab).

When calling:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.containerView
                  duration:0.4
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                animations:^{
                    [self.leftTab setTitle:@"Foo" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    [self.rightTab setTitle:@"Bar" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                completion:nil];
```

The text does change, but the non-disabled button, resizes its text.

I'm using `UIButton setTitle:forState:]` which usually works fine, but in this case I must be missing something silly. Any ideas on how to fix the resizing problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me. The animation didn't appear on the other tab, because it was disabled. I disabled animations on the other tab by using `[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO]`.